# Unable to play songs/videos from mounted android phone

Tags: 12.04, mount, video, android, mp3

I have successfully mounted my android(JB) phone with ubuntu 12.04 lts. Everything is fine, when i connect my phone to laptop a window appears with memory card and phone memory. I can copy/paste files from system to phone and phone to system.

Now my problem is that I can't play songs/videos from memory card or phone memory.
I am new to Ubuntu. Now only started to understand this platform.
 Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0):

Dude, there is some problem with mounting android phones in the Ubuntu 12.04.
and  you didn't specified the phone type of yours. so i'll prefer to copy the contents first before using them. my nexus can't mount its internal storage(i think the mounting issue is only for internal storage) .so i use adb push/pull to copy files.

Comment: Sorry. I am using Galaxy Trend GT-S7392.

Comment: did you tried to install mtp-tools

Comment: Yes. I have installed MTP-tools. I think Shaakunthala is right.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand that Android presents its internal and external storage to PC using [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol). It is not the same as USB mass storage where you mount a FAT filesystem.

MTP has certain limitations. I'm not sure of the exact limitation here, may be the because MTP limits one operation at a time, which makes you cannot directly play a file in an MTP device. First you have to copy the file to your computer. Even in Windows OS (which originally introduced it), this is it

When you connect a MTP device to a computer, do not expect the comfort you had with mass storage devices.

Secondly, Ubuntu 12.04 has poor MTP support. I understand that you are on a LTS release. But no choice, you will have to upgrade if you need proper MTP support. In Ubuntu 13.04+, MTP works well.